# Decimal stores precision from parsed string in C#? What are the implications?

Tags: c#, string, decimal, string-formatting

During a conversation on IRC, someone pointed out the following:

```
decimal.Parse("1.0000").ToString() // 1.0000
decimal.Parse("1.00").ToString() // 1.00
```

How/why does the `decimal` type retain precision (or, rather, significant figures) like this? I was under the impression that the two values are equal, not distinct.

This also raises further questions:

- How is the number of significant figures decided during mathematical operations?
- Does the number of significant figures get retained during serialization?
- Does the current culture affect the way this is handled?

Comment: As to [how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) it does: "The binary representation of a Decimal value consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the 96-bit integer and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28." -- the scaling factor is a discrete component.

Comment: @pst - So is the scaling factor solely responsible for significant figures? i.e. `1.0000` is `10000 / 10^4` and `1.00` is `100 / 10^2`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**How is the number of significant figures decided during mathematical operations?**

This is specified in the [ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) C# 4 specification 11.1.7 p.112

> A decimal is represented as an integer scaled by a power of ten. For
>   decimals with an absolute value less than 1.0m, the value is exact to
>   at least the 28th decimal place. For decimals with an absolute value
>   greater than or equal to 1.0m, the value is exact to at least 28
>   digits.

**Does the number of significant figures get retained during serialization?**

Yes it does, with seriallization the value and its precision does not change

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public decimal Value;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal d1 = decimal.Parse("1.0000");
        decimal d2 = decimal.Parse("1.00");

        Debug.Assert(d1 ==d2);

        var foo1 = new Foo() {Value = d1};
        var foo2 = new Foo() {Value = d2};

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream("data.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, d1);
        stream.Close();

        formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        stream = new FileStream("data.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        decimal deserializedD1 = (decimal)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();

        Debug.Assert(d1 == deserializedD1);

        Console.WriteLine(d1); //1.0000
        Console.WriteLine(d2); //1.00
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedD1); //1.0000

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**Does the current culture affect the way this is handled?**

The current culture affects only how a decimal can be parsed from a string, for example it can handle **'.'** or **','** as a culture-specific decimal point symbol or the currency symbol, should you provide it, e.g. "£123.4500". Culture does not change the way an object is stored internally and it does not affect its precision.

Internally, [decimal has](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) a mantissa, an exponent and a sign, so no space for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

A [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) consists of a 96-bit integer and a scaling factor (number of digits after the decimal point), which ranges from 0 to 28.  Thus:

- 1.000 becomes 1000 with scaling factor 3.

Comment: How does the scaling factor get affected by mathematical operations and serialization?

Comment: The scaling factor is included in the Decimal value's serialized form, as obtained by calling the GetBits method.  Also, as specified in the documentation, "[t]railing zeroes do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations."

Answer (score 1):

In addition to post I see here, I would personally add a side note:

**always** during persistence manipulations with floating point/decimal/double numbers consider the `culture` you're in, or you're going to save in. The code like here written is first, but definitive pass to complete mess and *non* culture independent architecture.

Use  [Decimal.Parse (String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/t7xswkc6.aspx).

In my opinion, that methods (`Parse From/To`) that lack of `Culture` parameter have to be removed from the library to force a developer to think about that very important aspect.